# What would you call parts of dialogue?

Tags: meaning, dialogue

As in

> 'The cat jumped over the dog,' Jack said

What would you call the "Jack said" part?

Comment: *Reporting speech*...??

Comment: In 'Jack said', 'said' is the introducing verb; Jack is the subject. 'Jack said' is the introductory sentence of the direct speech.